# From where did Loyola borrow the idea of “spiritual inebriation”?

Tags: prayer, blood-of-christ, ignatian-spirituality, st-ignatius-loyola

[***Anima Christi***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anima_Christi), the famous prayer of St Ignatius Loyola  has this verse:

> "Blood of Christ, inebriate me".

Clearly, it is not the physical inebriation, but the spiritual one that Loyola had in mind.

This prayer is found in the very first page of his famous [*Spiritual Exercises*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritual_Exercises) book (1522-1524).  [English translation by Louis J. Puhl, S.J.](https://archive.org/details/spiritualexercis0000loui/page/n17/mode/2up) (1959):

> Soul of Christ, sanctify me
> Body of Christ, save me
> **Blood of Christ, inebriate me**
> Water from the side of Christ, wash me
> Passion of Christ, strengthen me
> O good Jesus, hear me
> Within Thy wounds hide me
> Permit me not to be separated from Thee
> From the wicked foe defend me
> At the hour of my death call me
> And bid me come to thee
> That with Thy saints I may praise Thee
> For ever and ever.  Amen.

My question is: **Did Loyola borrow his idea of spiritual inebriation from the Scriptures?**

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you (or someone in the community, maybe myself some day!) could find the book / writing in which that prayer came from, so we can have better context for an answer.  At least a link to the whole prayer.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple the `Anima Christi`  is one of those prayers that is in nearly every Catholic prayer book.  I had no idea it was attributed to St. Ignatius until reading this question!

Comment: @PeterTurner Decided to write an answer to this Question.  Turns out it is from Pope John XXII.  I welcome your input about my interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that St. Ignatius Loyola borrowed it from a hymn (c. 1330) [attributed to Pope John XXII (1316-34)](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/fein-harley2253-volume-2-article-19-introduction) codified in a medieval book designated as [MS Harley 2253](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Lyrics) dated ca. 1340.  Here's the rendition from that manuscript as [digitized in 2014](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/fein-harley2253-volume-2-article-19):

**Latin**:

> Anima Christi, sanctifica me.
> Corpus Christi, salva me.
> **Sanguis Christi, inebria me.**
> Aqua lateris Christi, lava me.
> Passio Christi, conforta me.
> O bone Iesu, exaudi me
> Et non me permittas separari a te.
> Ab hoste maligno defende me.
> In hora mortis voca me,
> Et pone me iuxta te
> Ut cum angelis tuis laudem te
> In secula seculorum. Amen.

**English**:

> Soul of Christ, sanctify me.
> Body of Christ, save me.
> **Blood of Christ, intoxicate me.**
> Water from the side of Christ, wash me.
> Passion of Christ, comfort me.
> O good Jesus, hearken to me
> And do not allow me to be separated from you.
> Defend me from the evil enemy.
> Call me at the hour of death,
> And set me beside you
> So that I may praise you with your angels
> Forever and ever. Amen.

So the question then becomes **whether Pope John XXII borrow that idea from Scripture?**

Based on [St. John Henry Newman's translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anima_Christi#Text) (from the Latin *Sanguis Christi, inebria me*) which is:

> Blood of Christ, fill all my veins;

I would attribute the poem to be **poetic description** instead of borrowing from Scripture.  I mean poetic description of being **united with Christ** through the sacrament of the Eucharist, since even the meaning of drinking from the cup (i.e. receiving the blood of Christ in the Eucharist) in Catholicism is *not* as literal "filling all our [blood] veins", but ["a sign of courageous discipleship"](https://uscatholic.org/articles/201109/why-drink-from-the-cup/) (per Matt 20:22), in great contrast with [the Protestant Reformed meaning](https://www.desiringgod.org/articles/what-is-the-lords-supper) (as ordinance, Luke 22:19, and also to proclaim the Lord's death until he comes, 1 Cor 11:26) or with Jesus's own meaning (as participating in the new covenant since his blood is the blood of the new covenant, Matt 26:28).  This poetic sense matches well with other lines in the poem.  **That line can then be interpreted as envisioning Christ's lifeblood to be so integrated to our lifeblood that we are intoxicated with enthusiasm to live for Christ.**

Searching the web, I found these:

- A [Catholic blog article](https://www.catholicsistas.com/blood-christ-inebriate/) that provides a line-by-line prayer reflection interprets similarly in terms of animating our lifeblood:

  > What does this mean? What are we asking?
  >
  > First, let’s look at the definition of inebriate. When one thinks of inebriate one’s mind thinks “to be drunk, intoxicated”.
  >
  > I looked it up and there is one other definition. Inebriate is a transitive verb meaning to exhilarate or stupefy as if by liquor. AS IF, not necessarily BY liquor. Exhilarate means extreme excitement. So when we are saying “Blood of Christ, inebriate me” we are asking Christ to fill us with his Life giving blood to the point of exhilaration! After all, without Blood, we cannot LIVE.
- [This blog article](https://thevalueofsparrows.wordpress.com/2018/06/04/anima-christi-chapter-four-part-one-blood-of-christ-inebriate-me-by-marie-paul-curley/) also has a similar interpretation (in the context of communion in the Mass) but expressed as "the elation of being loved by God in Christ":

  > Many saints have struggled to express their devotion to the Precious Blood of Jesus.  Saint Catherine of Siena meditated so deeply on the passion and death of Jesus that she begins many of her letters with the phrase, “In His Precious Blood.”
  >
  > In the Mass, we are invited to enter anew into this shedding of Christ’s blood for us.  Though Jesus is fully present under both the consecrated bread and wine, the bread and wine are separate and are consecrated separately.  This separation is symbolic of the death of Jesus – the separation of his blood from his body.  It is another reminder of the reality we celebrate in every Eucharist: Jesus offering himself for our salvation.  This petition, Blood of Christ, inebriate me, invites us deeper into the mystery of our redemption.
  >
  > ... inebriate me
  >
  > A clue to our spiritual tradition is included in the second part of this petition.
  >
  > Considering the sacrificial nature of the words, *Blood of Christ*, wouldn’t we expect the invocation to be “save me” or “cleanse me”?  Instead, we pray with these unexpected words: inebriate me.  “Inebriate” is a term usually associated with a drunken, stupefied state.  When someone is inebriated, they are taken over by alcohol; their behavior changes.  When we pray this petition, we are asking to get drunk or to be immersed in Jesus.  We ask Jesus to flood us with himself, with his life and love, so that he can take over in us.  We ask Jesus to begin or to deepen that process by which we are transformed into him.
  >
  > “To be inebriated” is also used to describe being immersed in an experience, for example, inebriated with joy.  **To be inebriated changes our attitudes and our behavior.**  In this petition, then, we are clearly not focusing solely on the sorrow we could feel over the passion and death of Jesus.  Instead, **we are asking for the grace to be immersed and transformed by the Precious Blood of Christ.**  Bathed and inebriated in the love of Jesus, we can enter more fully into his resurrection, the fullness of life he offers to us.  T**he elation of being loved by God in Christ transforms our vision of ourselves, others, the world, our future, our way of living Christ in the world.**
- A [different interpretation by Mother Mary Francis, PCC](https://susanjoan.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/blood-of-christ-inebriate-me/) refers to the Pentecost Day experience of the apostles that @KenGraham's answer mentions (emphasis mine), but NOT Pentecostal style uncontrollable behavior:

  > [T]his inebriation is not of the senses. It may have nothing whatsoever to do with emotional response or lack of response. **It means that the spirit is enlivened, and the body exhilarated, not by what they feel but by what they can do.** We see something of this in the Acts of the Apostles when, on the first Pentecost morning, the disciples were speaking with such **enlivenment** as no one had seen in them before. They were addressing the crowds with an exhilaration that was completely new and far beyond their own powers and ordinary way of acting. The Pentecostal apostles were obviously exceeding their own potential. …They were inebriated with the blood of Christ, whose effects the Holy Spirit was at that moment bringing to climactic action. And whenever we are enabled by the Holy Spirit to exceed ourselves, to surpass our natural capabilities, we are experiencing in our measure and expressing within our possibilities the inebriation that is the effect of the blood of Christ outpoured.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, GratefulDisciple. It could be true that Pope John XXII originally wrote the prayer. He was, however, better known for his political affiliations and favouritism than for spiritual endeavours. It was thus possible that the prayer got little attention from the faithful during his papacy and thereafter till it was made popular by St Ignatius. Anyway, most of the pdf texts on internet attribute the authorship to St Ignatius.

Answer (score 1):

**From where did Loyola borrow the idea of “*spiritual inebriation*”?**

*Did Loyola borrow his idea of spiritual inebriation from the Scriptures?*

Impossible to know for sure, but it is definitely quite possible.

> **Spiritual drunkenness** refers to a phenomenon seen in some Christian denominations, particularly those associated with Pentecostalism and the Charismatic Movement, in which individuals who are said to be experiencing intense momentary visitations of—or even possession by—the Holy Spirit exhibit a range of behaviors resembling signs of moderate to severe alcoholic inebriation, including unsteadiness, uncontrollable laughter, silly expressions or gestures, verbal or nonverbal shouting (not typically in the form of glossolalia), sudden intense fatigue, and temporary unconsciousness. The phenomenon typically occurs during Pentecostal and charismatic church services, usually at the prompting of a preacher or pastor, and most often involving multiple members of a congregation at a time, generally after having been "transferred" from one person to another via respiratory blowing or laying on of hands. It also can occur at more intimate settings including housegroups and fellowship meetings of believers, wherever the Holy Spirit is free to move and have His way. The experiences are meant to bring people into a deeper encounter of God's love, power, presence and joy. The result should be a positive one, leading one to a more holy and joyous life.
>
> The concept of spiritual drunkenness is controversial among non-Pentecostal denominations. Opponents cite a lack of explicit biblical description of anything resembling spiritual drunkenness,[1] and some posit that the behaviors may even be the product of demonic influence.
>
> The Bible however does liken being filled with the Holy Spirit to wine, “And be not drunk with wine, wherein is excess; but be filled with the Spirit." Ephesians 5:18 Acts 2:1-15 says 'When the day of Pentecost came, they were all together in one place. Suddenly a sound like a mighty rushing wind came from heaven and filled the whole house where they were sitting. They saw tongues like flames of fire that separated and came to rest on each of them. And they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak in other tongues as the Spirit enabled them. Now there were dwelling in Jerusalem God-fearing Jews from every nation under heaven. And when this sound rang out, a crowd came together in bewilderment, because each one heard them speaking his own language.
>
> Astounded and amazed, they asked, “Are not all these men who are speaking Galileans? How is it then that each of us hears them in his own native language? Parthians, Medes, and Elamites; residents of Mesopotamia, Judea and Cappadocia, Pontus and Asia, Phrygia and Pamphylia, Egypt and the parts of Libya near Cyrene; visitors from Rome, both Jews and converts to Judaism; Cretans and Arabs—we hear them declaring the wonders of God in our own tongues!” Astounded and perplexed, they asked one another, “What does this mean?” But others mocked them and said, “They are drunk on new wine!”
>
> Then Peter stood up with the Eleven, lifted up his voice, and addressed the crowd: “Men of Judea and all who dwell in Jerusalem, let this be known to you, and listen carefully to my words. These men are not drunk, as you suppose. It is only the third hour of the day!'
>
> Those who have been 'drunk in the Holy Spirit' describe themselves as being overcome by God's presence and His love with the ability to speak in other tongues powerfully. Some report feeling like they have a new confidence and desire to preach to anyone about Jesus without any fear. The Holy Spirit's presence liberates them. This is because 'where the Spirit of the Lord is there is freedom' 2 Corinthians 3:17. The Holy Spirit has encountered them in a very powerful way. Many who get drunk in the Holy Spirit describe their relationship with Him becoming deeper and more fulfilling. - [Spiritual Drunkenness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritual_drunkenness)

Answer (score 0):

There is something worth referring to in 1 Sam 1:9-15 where we see the childless Hanna speaking to the Lord:

> Once when they had finished eating and drinking in Shiloh, Hannah stood up. Now Eli the priest was sitting on his chair by the doorpost of the Lord’s house. In her deep anguish Hannah prayed to the Lord, weeping bitterly. And she made a vow, saying, “Lord Almighty, if you will only look on your servant’s misery and remember me, and not forget your servant but give her a son, then I will give him to the Lord for all the days of his life, and no razor will ever be used on his head.” As she kept on praying to the Lord, Eli observed her mouth. Hannah was praying in her heart, and her lips were moving but her voice was not heard. Eli thought she was drunk and said to her, “How long are you going to stay drunk? Put away your wine.”
> “Not so, my lord,” Hannah replied, “I am a woman who is deeply troubled. I have not been drinking wine or beer; I was pouring out my soul to the Lord.

In my personal view, the author of *Anima Christi* must have had in mind, the spiritually inebriated state of Hanna while writing the verse "Blood of Christ, inebriate me ".

Comment: 2 problems though: 1) You haven't made connection with "Blood" nor with "Christ".  2) The text did *NOT* say Hanna was praying in a state of inebriated, but simply inaudible prayer with Eli's only see the lips moving.  It was Eli who thought Hanna was drunk

Comment: The state of deep meditative supplication that Hanna was in, could definitely be  termed as spiritual inebriation where one is oblivious to the surroundings. Eli was not wrong in interpreting the visuals as physical inebriation, by human standards. And see the apt reply of Hanna:! I was pouring my soul out before the Lord . Did Eli again interpret her reply as one out of physical drunkenness . He didn't , for he blesses her .

Comment: I also think Eli was not wrong.  This is the case of praying fervently.  But the petition "Blood of Christ, inebriate me" is that of asking Jesus to *produce* the inebriation, NOT one that we initiate.  I'm not saying we couldn't pray *Anima Christi* fervently like Hanna, but we need to match the verse with a better (possible) Biblical reference.  KenGraham's passage comes closer than Hanna's passage, because in Acts 2 the effect is produced in us, but I still wouldn't use it since the Apostles didn't request Jesus for inebriation, nor link it to crucifixion (blood).

Comment: GratefulDisciple, I think we need to define intoxication wrt spirituality. Before the invention of anaesthesia, patients were sedated with opium etc so as to make them insensitive to pain. We need see inebriation not as a state of ' kick' but as one of total detachment to wordly affairs. Incidentally, some cults in Oriental religions see physical intoxication as a way to spiritual intoxication. Of course, Christian values cannot support their arguments.

Comment: It is not enough that we ask Jesus to inebriate us spiritually. We need to prepare ourselves for it. See that Jesus sought the willingness of his beneficiaries before working miracles on them.